# Choosing GCC version when building ( setup.py )

Tags: python, gcc, distutils

I am trying to build a python module (scikit.timeseries) using

```
python setup.py build
```

but it's erroring out like this :

```
/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c'
gcc-4.0: scikits/timeseries/src/cseries.c
sh: gcc-4.0: command not found
```

This is because I'm on OSX Lion and gcc-4.0 doesn't exit, gcc does though :

```
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.0
```

but it is aliased to gcc not gcc-4.0 . How can I tell setup.py to look for **gcc** instead of **gcc-4.0** ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
python setup.py build
```