# Compilation error when using gcc in OSX 10.10.5

Tags: python, macos, gcc, osx-yosemite

I am trying to install a python package by using `python setup.py install` but at some point of the installation procedure an error is raised:

```
gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-arch’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Previously, I installed Xcode 7.0 and their respective Command Line Tools for Xcode 7. The compiler seems to be in `which gcc` local `/usr/local/bin/gcc`. However, when I tried `gcc -v` I got `Segmentation fault: 11`. Moreover, when I tried `/usr/bin/gcc -v` I got

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Then, the installed compiler seems to be in a different location. A similar issue was raised in [Command line tool installed, but gcc/g++ compiler not working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182083/command-line-tool-installed-but-gcc-g-compiler-not-working?newreg=d874000f6aa847b8869f8775187c6684) but there is not a clear solution to the problem. Do you have any idea how can I can fix it (link to the actual installed compiler to continue the installation of the Python package)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to look at what environment variables are set that would affect either path or compiler operation.

Comment: You shouldn't need that `--prefix` if the Xcode command line tools are installed (they get installed into `/usr/bin`).  Use `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: When I typed `xcode-select --install` this is what I got `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates` @Droppy

Comment: OK drop the `--prefix` and use `CC=clang ./configure <other-options>`.

Comment: @Droppy Which file do I need to modify?

Comment: Did you maybe install `gcc` using `homebrew`? That would place it in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [@Droppy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3588973/droppy)'s comment: xcode doesn't install gcc in /usr/local/bin (OP did not clarify where it came from).  MacPorts would put it in /opt/local/bin/gcc, but omit to select the current port.  So `CC=clang` is the simplest way to answer it.  However, OP is asking how to override it in `setup.py`.

*That* has been discussed in these questions:

- [Choosing GCC version when building ( setup.py )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016520/choosing-gcc-version-when-building-setup-py)
- [How may I override the compiler (gcc) flags that setup.py uses by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928110/how-may-i-override-the-compiler-gcc-flags-that-setup-py-uses-by-default)
- [How to tell distutils to use gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737260/how-to-tell-distutils-to-use-gcc)

The [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8016961/4518274) is most pertinent, leading to this suggestion:

```
CC=/usr/bin/clang CFLAGS="-O" python setup.py build
```

(clang simply ignores most of the gcc options, not even giving a warning, but setting `CFLAGS` can help persuade the python script to not try options that clang is unlikely to support).